# Kivyで作ったアプリをmacOSXで動かしたい

Tags: python, kivy

タイトルの通りで、公式チュートリアルに書いてあるPongGameを写経したもの（動作は確認しました）を、macOSXアプリとしてパッケージングしたいのですが、公式
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-osx.html
に載っている、Pyinstallerを使って、specファイルを編集（Treeを追加）する方法では

## -*- Pyinstallerエラー -*-

```
43467 WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Pong/zerokara/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/kivy_install/data/style.kv'
```

となってしまいます。
specファイルはこのようになっています。（COLLECTにTreeを指定しただけです）

## -*- main.spec -*-

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Pong/zerokara'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Pong/zerokara'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='main.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

もう一つの方法として紹介されているbuildozerを使う方法では、main.pyのあるディレクトリで
$buildozer init
$buildozer osx debug
をしても、

## -*- Buildozerエラー -*-

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 121, in build_package
    app_deps = open('requirements.txt').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

となってしまいます。
buildozer.specはこうなっています。（一切編集していないです）

## -*- buildozer.spec -*-

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 1

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

## -*- 追記 -*-

何故かPyinstallerの方で一切の変更を加えずspecファイルのビルドを4回繰り返したところ、エラーが

```
43467 WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Pong/zerokara/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/kivy_install/data/style.kv'
```

が2回、

```
47566 WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Pong/username/dist/main/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/dist/main/docutils/writers/html4css1/html4css1.css'
```

が1回と変わっていき、最終的にパッケージングできました。

Comment: どちらもエラー文に書いてあるとおりで、Pyinstallerでは `style.kv` 、Buildozerでは `requirements.txt` が無いのではないでしょうか？ドキュメントを参照する限りは必要なさそうですが、一旦それぞれで空のファイルを作って再度実行してみると直るかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうごいます。
Buildozerの方は
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py"
中のエラーなので、targetsディレクトリにrequirements.txtを作っておいてみたのですが、全く同じエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: Pyinstallerの方は今度は
324237 WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/fukudajun/PycharmProjects/Kivy/Pong/zerokara/.buildozer/osx/platform/kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/bin/python3'
というエラーが出て、該当ディレクトリにpython3のエイリアスはあるのですが認識してくれないみたいです